# Semiconductor SPDT-switch - use outputs as inputs?

Tags: switches

Can the outputs of a semiconductor SPDT-switch be used as inputs if I reverse the switch? I can't see why it shouldn't work, but I though I'd ask anyway.

Comment: An electromechanical switch don't have outputs and inputs - they have connections.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention that it's a semiconductor device. I'll edit the post.

Comment: The datasheet will tell you.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention which chip you are referring to, but in general a CMOS switch (CD4066 etc.) is bi-directional. The only requirement is that both voltages (input and output) are within the allowed range (in general 'within the power supply range', where the power pins can be separate from the ground and logic power.)

Comment: The switch is Mini-Circuits SWMA-2-50DR+. Can't see any information on this subject in the datasheet, but maybe I just don't know where to look.

Comment: That is not a general-purpose CMOS switch but a HF switch. I have no experience with such a switch, and I would not assume it to be totally bi-directional without further investigation. I would probably just use it as directed by the datasheet.